# libsane-dev dependences

Tags: hplip

I have problem with **libsane-dev**.

I tried install *libsane-dev* for HPLIP drivers 3.15.9 (drivers needs it).
I got log with wrong dependence:

*libsane-dev needs: libsane (= 1.0.23-3ubuntu3) but 1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1 will be installed.*

How should I force (resole) to install correct libsane-dev version?

Now, I have installed packages:

```
xxxx~$ dpkg -l | grep sane
ii  libsane:amd64                                         1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1                                   amd64        API library for scanners
ii  libsane-common                                        1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1                                   amd64        API library for scanners -- documentation and support files
rc  libsane-hpaio                                         3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2                                   amd64        HP SANE backend for multi-function peripherals
ii  sane                                                  1.0.14-9                                            amd64        scanner graphical frontends
ii  sane-utils                                            1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1                                   amd64        API library for scanners -- utilities
ii  xsane                                                 0.998-5ubuntu1                                      amd64        featureful graphical frontend for SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)
ii  xsane-common                                          0.998-5ubuntu1                                      all          featureful graphical frontend for SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)

xxxx~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

xxxx~$ apt-cache policy libsane-dev libsane
libsane-dev:
Zainstalowana: (brak)
Kandydująca:   1.0.23-3ubuntu3
Tabela wersji:
1.0.23-3ubuntu3 0
500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

libsane:
Zainstalowana: 1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1
Kandydująca:   1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1
Tabela wersji:
*** 1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1 0
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
1.0.23-3ubuntu3 0
500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

xxxx~$ uname -a 
Linux XXXXX 3.16.0-52-generic #71~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 17:24:53 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a apt-cache policy libsane-dev libsane `

Comment: use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` it'll have better offers

Answer (score 2):

You disabled the `trusty-update` PPA *after* the installation of `libsane`.

Open <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd> and set a thick for `trusty-updates` in the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd>.

[image]

Now open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsane-dev
```